# ClickHouse - Too many links

Tags: clickhouse

I am testing a ClickHouse server with heavy insertion and have encountered that the server is in a state that it stops processing insertions with “Too many links” exceptions. Based on observations, I don’t think it could recover from the state even though I stopped insertion. I also noticed that the “Too many links” exception message come every millisecond which results server log files fill-up quickly.

Test Env. & How to reproduce:

- Sever: Dual xxx 14 cores @ 2.4 GHz, 56 vCPU with 256GB mem. Centos 7, clickhouse-server: 21.2.2 revision 54447 (tested with 21.8 also)
- Engine: MergeTree PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(time_generated)
  ORDER BY time_generated
- 15 clients (10 clickhouse-client, 5 CPP clients) continually inserting log data (~150 fields) with tsv format (bulk size is 500K rows) for a day or so

In this state, clickhouse-server is using 1.5 cores and w/o noticeable file I/O activities.
Other queries work.
To recover from the state, I deleted the temporary directory(s).

I don’t think we will normally insert this way (ignoring "Too many parts") in practice however wonder if this (going into this state) can be an issue. And, beside not inserting data abnormally, is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

Logs:

```
- client 
  Code: 252. DB::Exception: Received from xx:9000. DB::Exception: Too many parts (303). Merges are processing significantly slower than inserts..

- server: 
  2021.10.21 09:17:48.649609 [ 21223 ] {} <Error> auto DB::IBackgroundJobExecutor::jobExecutingTask()::(anonymous class)::operator()() const: Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 31, e.displayText() = File access error: Too many links: /var/lib/clickhouse/tmp/store/48c/48cab972-1221-4222-a5f4-ed3960a08f35/tmp_merge_20211021_452585_452597_1, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. Poco::FileImpl::handleLastErrorImpl(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) @ 0x11c42124 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. Poco::FileImpl::createDirectoryImpl() @ 0x11c4372f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. Poco::File::createDirectories() @ 0x11c456b7 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. DB::DiskLocal::createDirectories(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) @ 0xe79e358 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. DB::MergeTreeDataMergerMutator::mergePartsToTemporaryPart(DB::FutureMergedMutatedPart const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::BackgroundProcessListEntry<DB::MergeListElement, DB::MergeInfo>&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&, long, DB::Context const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<DB::IReservation, std::__1::default_delete<DB::IReservation> > const&, bool, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&) @ 0xf36ad8e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. DB::StorageMergeTree::mergeSelectedParts(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, bool, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, DB::StorageMergeTree::MergeMutateSelectedEntry&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&) @ 0xf10f108 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. ? @ 0xf12168c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. ? @ 0xf2cb076 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0x8513fb8 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda1'()>(void&&, void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda1'()&&...)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0x8515f6f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0x851158f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ? @ 0x8515023 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ? @ 0x7eb5 in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
13. __clone @ 0xfe8fd in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
(version 21.2.2.8 (official build))enter code here

--- with 21.8.
2021.10.25 08:29:18.354200 [ 55326 ] {} <Error> auto DB::IBackgroundJobExecutor::execute(DB::JobAndPool)::(anonymous class)::operator()() const: std::exception. Code: 1001, type: std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error, e.what() = filesystem error: in create_directory: Too many links [/var/lib/clickhouse/tmp/store/48c/48cab972-1221-4222-a5f4-ed3960a08f35/tmp_merge_20211024_906198_906236_1], Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. std::__1::system_error::system_error(std::__1::error_code, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) @ 0x1590de6f in ?
1. ? @ 0x158a171f in ?
2. ? @ 0x158a1136 in ?
3. ? @ 0x158a58f8 in ?
4. std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__create_directory(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code*) @ 0x158a646b in ?
5. std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__create_directories(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code*) @ 0x158a6125 in ?
6. std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__create_directories(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code*) @ 0x158a6189 in ?
7. DB::DiskLocal::createDirectories(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) @ 0xff032ec in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::MergeTreeDataMergerMutator::mergePartsToTemporaryPart(DB::FutureMergedMutatedPart const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::BackgroundProcessListEntry<DB::MergeListElement, DB::MergeInfo>&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&, long, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, std::__1::unique_ptr<DB::IReservation, std::__1::default_delete<DB::IReservation> > const&, bool, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, DB::MergeTreeData::MergingParams const&, DB::IMergeTreeDataPart const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) @ 0x10d14ff8 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
 9. DB::StorageMergeTree::mergeSelectedParts(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, bool, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, DB::StorageMergeTree::MergeMutateSelectedEntry&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&) @ 0x10eea024 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ? @ 0x10ef9937 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ? @ 0x10c40e77 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0x8ffab98 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda0'()>(void&&, void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda0'()&&...)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0x8ffc73f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0x8ff84ff in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. ? @ 0x8ffb763 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
16. ? @ 0x7eb5 in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
17. __clone @ 0xfe8fd in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so

Cannot print extra info for Poco::Exception (version 21.8.5.1.altinity+prestable (altinity build))
```

Comment: How often do you insert? Looks like the standard problem: inserts shouldn't occured too often, instead of this data should be accumulated into the batches and inserted ~1 per second. If this is impossible in your case there are couple of workarounds now:  from 3rd party tools to Buffer tables and asynchronous inserts inside the Clickhouse itself

Comment: Thanks Andres for the information. 
I don't control how often; 15 clients insert with 500K rows a batch. It took several seconds until the client gets the response from the server and immediately the client sends the next batch. If it receives an exception, it sleeps 10 seconds.
However I am not looking for a solution of higher injection. Rather to see if this is a known issue and when this happens, how we can recover it beside deleting temporary files. Or any other tips to prevent this, beside sending nicely (or using buffer and etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df -i /var/lib/clickhouse/`

`df -h /var/lib/clickhouse/`

1. upgrade CH to 21.8.10.19 https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/26471
2. https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/3174#issuecomment-423435071
3. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/merge-tree-settings/#parts-to-throw-insert

```
# cat /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/z_parts_to_throw.xml
<yandex>
    <merge_tree>
        <old_parts_lifetime>30</old_parts_lifetime>
        <parts_to_delay_insert>150</parts_to_delay_insert>
        <parts_to_throw_insert>900</parts_to_throw_insert>
        <max_delay_to_insert>5</max_delay_to_insert>
    </merge_tree>
</yandex>
```

4. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#background_pool_size

```
# cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/user_substitutes.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <background_pool_size>32</background_pool_size>
        </default>
    </profiles>
</yandex>
```

5. restart CH

Comment: Thanks Denny for the information. Good to know that there is a fix as well. Will study on the suggested parameters , upgrade and continue.